# Mysql, Dynamically Convert Rows to Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table of items (like below)

```
+------+--------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| prod | period | group | item_code | prop_code | value  |
+------+--------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|    3 | 199901 |     1 |       101 |         1 |  16240 |
|    3 | 199902 |     2 |       102 |         2 |   6142 |
|    3 | 199903 |     1 |       105 |         3 |    340 |
|    3 | 199904 |     1 |       106 |         4 |   5003 |
|    3 | 199905 |     1 |       201 |         5 |   3544 |
|    3 | 199906 |     1 |       202 |         6 |     13 |
|    3 | 199907 |     1 |       206 |         7 |      9 |
|    3 | 199908 |     1 |       301 |         8 |     64 |
|    3 | 199909 |     2 |       302 |         9 |  30408 |
|    3 | 199910 |     2 |       303 |        10 |    740 |
|    3 | 199911 |     1 |       304 |        11 |    660 |
|    3 | 199912 |     1 |       305 |        12 |   1113 |
|    4 | 200001 |     1 |       306 |        13 | 298881 |
|    4 | 200002 |     2 |       307 |        14 | 186097 |
|    4 | 200003 |     1 |       402 |        15 |    600 |
|    4 | 200004 |     2 |       403 |        16 | 164765 |
|    4 | 200005 |     2 |       404 |        17 | 203938 |
|    4 | 200006 |     2 |       405 |        18 |    195 |
|    4 | 200007 |     1 |       406 |        19 |     80 |
|    4 | 200008 |     2 |       409 |        20 |    970 |
|    4 | 200009 |     1 |       502 |        21 |  89012 |
|    4 | 200010 |     1 |       602 |        22 |  47473 |
|    4 | 200011 |     2 |       603 |        23 |    775 |
|    4 | 200012 |     1 |       604 |        24 |    335 |
+------+--------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

I am attempting to dynamically change the rows to columns where 'period' would be in columns and respective 'value' would be underneath the 'period' like this -

```
| prod | group | item_code | prop_code | 199901 | 199902 | 199903 | 199904 | 199905 | 199906 | 199907 | 199908 | 199909 | 199910 | 199911 | 199912 | 200001 | 200002 | 200003 | 200004 | 200005 | 200006 | 200007 | 200008 | 200009 | 200010 | 200011 | 200012 |
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: look for `MySQL dynamic pivot` on this site or on google

Comment: Thanks, I did,  but unable to build a query and hence the question here. tried something like this but keep getting errors SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN period = ',
      period,
      ' then value ELSE NULL end) AS `period', period, '`')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM items;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  prod, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM    items
                   GROUP   BY prod');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Comment: Edit your question and post what you tried there.  Also post the errors you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you've ran into maximum length of GROUP_CONCAT which is 1024 characters long.
you can use this `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len` to increase its length

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL; 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(CASE WHEN period = ', period, ' then value ELSE NULL end) AS period', period, '') ) INTO @sql FROM items; 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT prod,`group`,item_code,prop_code, ', @sql, ' FROM items GROUP BY prod,`group`,item_code,prop_code'); 
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44e6a4/2)

Comment: Many Thanks Tin Tran. I had to set the length to maximum possible 18446744073709551615 for the SQL to run as the table I have is big. Further I do not get any results (mysql returned an empty results) in phpMyAdmin despite being successfully executed. The same runs fine in Workbench. 
Also if I were to insert the results in a new table how would I do that